# Discrepancy between AbsoluteTiming and actual execution time with Table

Tags: evaluation

While trying to benchmark whether or not I could benefit from `ParallelTable[]` I ran into a rather strange discrepancy between the time reported by `//AbsoluteTiming` and the time that Mathematica reports on the bottom of the window.

For example, consider the evaluation of this simple function

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Table[x^2, {x, -10, 10, 0.001}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

The value reported on the bottom of the window by Mathematica is somewhere between 0.09 and 0.11 seconds on my machine, where as `//AbsoluteTiming` reports only around 0.0014 seconds.

This is a relatively quick evaluation, so maybe this isn't able to be properly measured. However if I increase the number of evaluations, the discrepancy becomes more pronounced. With a step size of `0.000001` the value returned by `//AbsoluteTiming` jumps to about 2.17 seconds, however the actual execution time reported by Mathematica is just over *72 seconds*.

What is going on here? Is there something going on behind the scene (such as formatting the list output) that `//AbsoluteTiming` doesn't account for?

Comment: Yes, the time reported by `EvaluationCompletionAction` includes formatting that `AbsoluteTiming` can't capture (since the result of `AbsoluteTiming` is part of what is being formatted.) If you suppress the output (`... ;//AbsoluteTiming`) the reported times should be much closer together.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` measures the time that the MathKernel needs for its computations. `Timing` factors in also the time spent in the FrontEnd.